# Difference between privacy considerations when comparing mobile apps with mobile web

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Sadly I know little to nothing about mobile app development and I am tasked with thinking through privacy considerations a user could have when using a mobile website vs its app equivalent.

For example, when a user browses our mobile website we can collect the following data:

- IP
- User agent
- OS information returned from Javascript, including screen resolution
- Cookies from the domain

Of course, this list isn't exhaustive.

So what can easily be collected from a user of a mobile app? (assuming no extra permissions were enabled)

- IP
- What's the equivalent of a user agent?
- What OS/device info is available?
- Do apps have "cookies"?
- What else?

Answer (score 1):

APMK, we can Collect the below data

1. Device location.
2. Device Name.
3. Device Version.
4. OS (Android/iOS/Windows)
5. Cooikes if we are using webview ..etc

Comment: Is there a simple app that will dump out this data to you, so I could see it on my device?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question requires more clarifications and answer to the following questions:

Do you have access to the source code ? If yes, you can track basically anything that's in the app using 3rd party tracking services like Google Analytics or other similar stuffs (even your own implementation). If not, do you have access to the API that's used by the application ? If yes, you can probably detect the OS since almost all request have a User-Agent attached to them, platform specific, but from the API requests you can't have much info.

I think the problem should be put the other way around, what do you want to track from a mobile app ? And I can tell you from my experience that there's almost nothing that can't be tracked from mobile apps if you have access to the source code. Regarding the permissions, off-course you won't be able to access something for which you didn't request any permissions, but you can check if the permission is granted anyway (maybe some other part of your app requested those permissions).

Also just a reminder, if you develop apps for EU, make sure you're GDPR compliant, the sanctions can be quite huge for a non-GDPR compliant app.

Comment: Yes we will have the code. The question is not what do we want to track, it is what tracking concerns could a user have, specifically. This is not GDRP related.

Comment: Can we see their IMEI number, their phone number, etc... These are the concerns we need to address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an App where you can find all the info of the Particular info https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quixom.deviceinfo

Check it out

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for.